# How to match partial strings in one table to ID in another table?

Tags: sql, string, reporting-services, inner-join, sql-like

I need to find a way to be able to find out who viewed, shared and downloaded a document.

I need to figure out a way to match the ID of the file in the string in the logDetail table to the documentID in another table, so i can match the files/document names to those ids.

Below shows part of my tables.

logDetail
[image]

documents

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You could do something like this:

```
select ld.*
from logDetail ld join
     documents d
     on ld.logDetail like concat('% ID ', d.documentId);
```

All the `logDetail` records that you show end with `' ID <number>'`, so this matches on that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If the id is always at the end of the log, you can use `like` in a join condition:

```
select *
from logdetail ld
inner join documents d 
    on l.logdetail like concat('%', d.documentid)
```

You can even be more precise, if the string format is fixed:

```
select *
from logdetail ld
inner join documents d 
    on l.logdetail = concat('Load Shared Document with ID ', d.documentid)
```